# Change Regex to only accept specified characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have the regex in a javascript file as:

```
function (value) {
    regex = new RegExp("[\<|\>|\"|\'|\%|\;|\(|\)|\&|\_|\.]", "i");
    return !regex.test(value);
}
```

Rather than specifying what characters are not allowed, how can I state what characters are allowed? The characters I want are a-z A-Z 0-9 (and also the actual character "-" but not at the start or end, only inbetween). Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Sorry, also there should be a minimum of 6 characters entered please... Currently, its confusing which answer is correct as each answer has one vote!

Comment: I updated my answer with a Min 6 char solution

Comment: For the length requirement, why don't you just test for the length of the string, if the regex matches? See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$");`

Again the classical "normal* (special normal*)*" pattern ;)

The function body becomes:

```
function (value) {
    regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$");
    return regex.test(value) && value.length >= 6;
}
```

edit: made grouping non capturing since no capture is done here

Comment: Thanks for the continued help! Question: what does "i" in the original code do?

Comment: @ASmith it tells that the match should be case insensitive -- which didn't really make sense anyway since the regex didn't contain any alphabetic characters to start with ;)

Answer (score 1):

The restriction on not having the dash at the start or end makes the regex a little more complicated. The regex below first matches a single character, then it optionally matches zero or more characters including dash before ending on a non-dash character.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$/
```

Comment: No, not at all: look at my answer

Comment: +1 Although it won't accept the empty string. Not sure if the OP wanted that or not, just noting it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
regex = new RegExp("^(?!-)[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]$", "i");
```

`^` anchors to the start of the string

`(?!-)` a negative look ahead ensuring the string does not start with a dash

`[a-z0-9-]*` 0 or more of the characters inside the class

`[a-z0-9]$` ends with a character from the class

See this [regex here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vg7b)

**Update**

This is a variant using two lookaheads, this would also accept the empty string

```
^(?!-)(?!.*-$)[a-z0-9-]*$
```

[See it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vg7e)

**Update 2: Minimum 6 characters**

```
^(?!-)[a-z0-9-]{5,}[a-z0-9]$
```

[See it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vg7h)

To counter the comment

> It is actually too complicated a regex -- and definitely slower than
>   my regex

I did a small benchmark (in Perl, shouldn't be a big deal)

```
sub WithLookahead($) {
    my $string = shift;

    return $string =~ /^(?!-)[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]$/i;
}

sub WithOutLookahead($) {
    my $string = shift;

    return ( $string =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/
          && length($string) >= 6 );
}

sub BenchmarkLookahead($) {
    use Benchmark;
    my $testString = shift;

    my $t0 = Benchmark->new;
    for ( 0 .. 10000000 ) {
        my $result = WithLookahead($testString);
    }
    my $t1 = Benchmark->new;

    my $t2 = Benchmark->new;
    for ( 0 .. 10000000 ) {
        my $result = WithOutLookahead($testString);
    }
    my $t3 = Benchmark->new;

    my $tdWith    = timediff( $t1, $t0 );
    my $tdWithOut = timediff( $t3, $t2 );
    print "the code with Lookahead and test string \"$testString\" took:",    timestr($tdWith),    "\n";
    print "the code without Lookahead and test string \"$testString\" took:", timestr($tdWithOut), "\n";
}
```

**Result**

> the code with Lookahead and test string "Foo-Bar" took:16 wallclock secs (14.94 usr +  0.00 sys = 14.94 CPU)
>   the code without Lookahead and test string "Foo-Bar" took:18 wallclock secs (17.50 usr +  0.02 sys = 17.52 CPU)
>   the code with Lookahead and test string "-Foo-Bar" took:13 wallclock secs (12.03 usr +  0.00 sys = 12.03 CPU)
>   the code without Lookahead and test string "-Foo-Bar" took:14 wallclock secs (13.44 usr +  0.00 sys = 13.44 CPU)
>   the code with Lookahead and test string "Foo-Bar-" took:17 wallclock secs (15.28 usr +  0.00 sys = 15.28 CPU)
>   the code without Lookahead and test string "Foo-Bar-" took:23 wallclock secs (21.61 usr +  0.02 sys = 21.63 CPU)
>   the code with Lookahead and test string "Foo" took:14 wallclock secs (13.70 usr +  0.00 sys = 13.70 CPU)
>   the code without Lookahead and test string "Foo" took:19 wallclock secs (17.09 usr +  0.02 sys = 17.11 CPU)

So overall my regex with the negative lookahead is a bit quicker than the combination of a simpler regex in combination with a external length check. But I needed to call each code 10000000 times to get significant results, so I don't think its a performance decision which one to use.

Comment: Nice use of a negative look ahead.

Comment: Hi, so the final code would be: `regex = new RegExp("^(?!-)[a-z0-9-]{5,}[a-z0-9]$", "i"); `?

Comment: It is actually too complicated a regex -- *and* definitely slower than my regex.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the examples you gave from that site. It was a great tool to show the code ;)

Comment: @fge this is still a simple regex, the only advanced part is a very basic lookahead. Your regex has nested quantifiers, so I am quite sure your statement mine is "definitely slower" is not true, or have you run a benchmark?

Comment: @stema: lots of benchmarks at some times, yes. But look at my nested quantifier: it applies only to `normal`, not `special`! This part will only ever be entered if you have `special` in your input and will swallow `normal*`, etc etc, as long as it is encountered. It validates all the input in one pass, and fails quickly.

Comment: @fge sorry the part of my comment about the nested quantifiers is not correct, I realized that sometime after posting. To clarify the performance question I did a small benchmark in Perl. My solution seems to be a bit quicker, but I think its not such a big issue to make here a performance problem out of it.